# Picasso error loading some images in recycler view

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I using picasso to load some images in recycler view adapter but some images show it success loading but it's actually not displayed

Here is my image view

```
   <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_main_imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:src="@drawable/image" />
```

the adapter code

```
 if (holder instanceof NewsViewHolder) {


        ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsTitleTextView.setText(currentArticle.getTitle().trim());
        ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsDateTextView.setText(DateUtils.getDisplayDate(currentArticle.getPublishedAt(), context));

        if (!currentArticle.getThumbnail().isEmpty()) {
            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).higherLevelSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsTitleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            //Load the news image
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(currentArticle.getThumbnail().trim())
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .into(((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsMainImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsImageScrim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsImageScrim.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            //Try again online if cache failed
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(currentArticle.getThumbnail().trim())
                                    .into(((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsMainImageView, new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {
                                            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsImageScrim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError() {
                                            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsImageScrim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            Timber.e("Could not fetch image");
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).higherLevelSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsMainImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((NewsViewHolder) holder).newsImageScrim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

So any one face this problem or have a solution for it

Comment: if (!currentArticle.getThumbnail().isEmpty()) 

What is it?

Comment: that's mean no image and he out of the loading condition but the image is actually has url and in the log it's loaded successfully and cached also but not displayed some images has this and their size is normal

Comment: show us the image url please

Comment: https://arabicedition.nature.com/cms/figure/index/59a816fb3cb388c1218b4570

Comment: replace https with http and update here the result

Comment: the problem with nor download the image because `onSuccess` is triggered but it's not displayed

Comment: u tried without callbacks also ?

Comment: yes no different

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glide](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/) instead its the best way to load images.

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'


String imgUrl = "img.jpg";
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);
```